# Why does key-change from C to C♯ sound so exotic than C to D♭?

Tags: theory, key, key-signatures, microtonality

I downloaded and retuned [Night Walk from Rhythm Tengoku](https://musescore.com/user/18410076/scores/5908807) from 12edo to [19edo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19_equal_temperament), along with some tweaks (correction of key signatures, and correction of range of the glockenspiel)

The original piece goes from C Major to D♭ Major, then to D Major, and then to E♭ Major.

When I retuned those to 19edo, it didn't sound too different. The chords sounded like slightly different quality, but not too much.

Since C♯ and D♭ are different notes in 19edo, I tried interpolating between C Major part and D♭ Major part with C♯ Major. And that's where it sounded so exotic. I won't say it's horrible though.

What's the reason? You can listen to the modified version [here](https://musescore.com/user/24185866/scores/6382025/s/u7h9-h). (WARNING: tuning doesn't work in mobile version of Musescore.)

Answer (score 2):

I will venture a mix of reasons, which I won't claim to be scientifically justified but I think substantially account for this experience. The two-step 19edo semitone (~126cents) is closer to the familiar 12edo semitone (100cents) than the one-step 19edo semitone(~63cents), although both are quite far off. However the two-step semitone is considerably closer to the "just diatonic semitone"(16:15=~112cents), which there may be justification for thinking this is the 'appropriate' semitone when we are doing a parallel key shift, though your mileage may vary. There also exists the "chromatic just semitone"(25:24=~71cents) which is in fact closer to the one-step 19edo semitone. However I think a considerably part of accounting for this experience is simply that a wider shift simply feels more acceptable to our ears than a narrower one. In the narrow shift the tones are too dissonant with the established preceding tonality, to a greater extent than with the wider shift. This is where I don't have a scientific justification, perhaps someone else can fill one in (or refute)

Comment: Matters are not helped by that extraordinary lead tone, which seems designed to evoke "overheating circuit board/batteries running out" regardless of what tuning is being used!